# how to click the menu option in the webpage(in IE) using excel macro after logged in

Tags: html, excel, vba

please anyone can help on the below macro. I am trying to log into the webpage (1) and click into the one of the menu (2), enter data into the field (3) and click save (4). so, this task has to repeat to save multiple data. so jobs (1,3,4) successfully working for me but struck with job 2. when i am trying to get ID to click one of the menu, the below is the code i get in the webpage and i plug the same into the getelementid but its not working me and its showing error when i run the code. believe i miss something here and hope any can help me plz,

**<a onclick="menuOnclick('/menu/insidemenu.php');"href="#"**

```
sub Code()
  Dim ie As Object
  Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  With ie
 .Visible = True
 .navigate "https://website_name/login.php"
  Do While .Busy
  DoEvents
  Loop
  Do While .readyState <> 4
  DoEvents
  Loop

  'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")

  .Document.GetElementByID("username").Value = "username"
  .Document.GetElementByID("password").Value = "password"
  .Document.GetElementByID("domain").Value = "domain"
  .Document.GetElementByID("login").Click
  **.Document.GetElementByID("menu/insidemenu.php").Click**

   End With
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This '**a**' tag does not have an '**id**' attribute, you can't use '**.Document.getElementById()**' function this time:

> <a onclick="menuOnclick('/menu/insidemenu.php');"href="#"

onclick is the event that fires when the 'a' tag is clicked. You have to access this tag through its parent tag (if it has an id attribute) or you can use '**.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")**' but it will return a collection of elements, so you have to specify the index of this 'a' tag inside the collection like this:

> **.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")[index]**

Where 'index' is a positive integer. And don't forget that indexes are zero based, so the first index is 0.

Comment: Peter Forgo, Appreciate your reply ! i tried elementsby tagname but the tagname "a" doesn't return related attribute. The attributes i see in the given HTML code is Onclick, href and class and none of them are showing in Debug. is there way i can debug ?

Comment: If it has a class attribute you can also use: .document.get ElementsByClassName("CLASS_NAME"). It will also return a collection of elements with the given class name. Can you copy/paste the full <a> tag for me? A screenshot from the full <body> would be  kindly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, Sorry for late reply. I couldn't able to post a screenshot because i am new member to this forum but I managed to save the image in this link "https://postimg.cc/CdmQmmb1". I tried with Class name but i am not getting any attributes in my debug.

Comment: Although I can't see the <a> element you specified on the screenshot, you should 
try this: `.Document.getElementById("side-menu").childNodes[3].childNodes[0].click`. This will reference the 'side-menu' element's (<ul>) 4th childnode, which is a <li> and it's 1st childNode, which is the <a> node you are looking for (hopefully). If you are looking for a different <a> node, you can do it in a similar way like I did. Look for the nearest parent node, which has an 'id' attribute and access the specified childNode like I did.

Comment: thanks for your reply. what you identified is correct and that's the <a> tag i am trying to click. Thought it makes sense, when i tried to run the given code, i get error "Compile error: Expected : End of statement". do i need to declare any datatype before run the code ? and i tried this way as well **.Document.GetElementByID("side-menu").ChildNodes [3].Click** but i get error of "run time error of 424: object required";

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that you have to put the index number is parantheses, like this: .Document.getElementById("side-menu").childNodes(3)childNodes(0).click